# How many mundus stones per zone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

What is the quantitative distribution of mundus stones in each zone?

That is, in the first zone of each alliance, how many mundus stones are there? And for the second zone in each alliance, and so on.

I know there are 13 mundus stones total, but how are they distributed?

This is surprisingly hard to find an answer to elsewhere without also spoiling what stones are in which zone and where they are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a [list of Mundus Stones on the wiki](https://elderscrollsonline.wiki.fextralife.com/Mundus+Stones). Without spoiling it, the general pattern is, the first zone for a faction has two, the next three zones have three, and the final zone has two. It's the same set for each faction in each zone as well.